# How to prevent scrolling while drawing inside Scrollview

Tags: android

I have got a drawing View and a `ScrollView` with Elements in it. The problem is, that I only could draw lines horizontally, because when I try to draw lines vertically the view is scrolling down because of the `ScrollView.`

When I delete the `ScrollView,` also the vertically lines could draw, but I need the `ScrollView` in order to display all the Elements.

I tried to change the `overScrollMode` in the `ScrollView,` but this didn't help.

How to prevent scrolling down the view, while I draw in drawing View?

Here's the corresponding part of `xml` file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/openproctScrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never">

    <FrameLayout

        android:id="@+id/drawingLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.unitnode.Drawing
            android:id="@+id/drawingView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls" />
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the drawing class:

```
public class Drawing extends View {
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
    public static String strichFarbeHex;
    private Path mPath;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private BlurMaskFilter mBlur;
    private MaskFilter mEmboss;
    private float mX, mY;

    public Drawing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPath = new Path();

        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[]{1, 1, 1}, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);

        this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                Log.d("onTouch", "onTouch");
                Log.d("x", String.valueOf(x));
                Log.d("y", String.valueOf(y));

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.d("a", "down");
                        Log.d("hier", "hier1");
                        touch_start(x, y);
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.d("onTouch", "onTouch2");
                        touch_move(x, y);
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.d("onTouch", "onTouch3");
                        touch_up();
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    // mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);

    public static String setStrichFarbe(String strichFarbe) {

        strichFarbeHex = strichFarbe;
        Log.d("strichFarbeHex", "strichFarbeHex " + strichFarbeHex);
        return strichFarbeHex;
    }

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        // mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        // mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SCREEN));
        // mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
        // mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {

        Log.d("onDraw", "onDraw " + mPath + "|" + mPaint);
        long startTime = this.getDrawingTime();
        Log.d("startTime", "startTime " + startTime);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        c.drawPaint(mPaint);

        // TODO: Ändern der Strichfarbe soll nicht komplett alles ändern, sondern nur den letzten Strich
        if (strichFarbeHex != null) {
            String strichFarbHexCode = getStrichFarbe();
            Log.d("strichFarbHexCode", "strichFarbHexCode " + strichFarbHexCode);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(strichFarbHexCode));
        } else {
            mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        c.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // wenn die Zurücktaste das erste Mal gedrückt wurde
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        }
        return true;
    }

    public String getStrichFarbe() {
        return strichFarbeHex;
    }
}
```

and this picture shows how it looks like:

[image]
Thanks for helping

Comment: While 'drawing' in the view, you should consume the touch event to prevent any further actions being taken on it (like scrolling). I'm guessing that's currently not happening, although we'd really need to see some relevant code to confirm.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have match_parent for both width and height? Where is ScrollView used? Can you show at least part od Draw method? Are you sure you have constant drawingView size during drawing?

Comment: I tried to use 'wrap_content' with 'layout_height' for the 'ScrollView', 'FrameLayout' and the drawing View. Nothing changed. Just when I use 'wrap_content' with the drawing View, the error occurs: "width and height must be > 0" references to the 'onSizeChanged( )' method of the Drawing class

Comment: well I discovered two possibilities: 1. limit the scrollbar in their height (the scrollbar should start after the drawing view, so that I draw also lines in vertical direction). 2. Just add the scrollbar to the Elements Layout. Anyone has idea how to change my layout/code to achieve that?

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue.

Try giving

```
getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

inside the *drawing function*.- onDraw(Canvas c)

Comment: Holy mother of Gods! This is perfect!